# Как менять отображение в зависимости от входного параметра

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, вёрстка

Доброго времени суток!
Описываю ситуацию:
Пишу декстопное приложение на C# с WPF (.NET 4.0). Есть главное окно программы, где располагается tabControl с dataGrid-ами, ниже splitter и еще один dataGrid - это отображение, скажем так, по-умолчанию. Нужно, что бы для некоторых пользователей (определить можно по параметру, который передается при запуске программы) отображение было иным.
Нашел такие варианты как: Page, UserControl. Ни с первым, ни со вторым опыта работы нет.
Так вот, может кто-то решал подобные задачи? Каким способом? И какие могут быть "подводные камни" при использовании Page и UserControl.

Обдумывал еще такой вариант:
Добавить еще 1 tabControl, в tabItem которого будут находиться необходимые отображения. Но тут получается - tabControl на tabControl-е. Даже если делать такой вариант - необходимо каким-то образом скрыть заголовки у tabControl, что бы не было визуального отображения.

Может быть много лишнего написал. Хотелось бы получить хотя бы "пинок" в нужном направлении :)

Comment: "Пинок" - перед написанием подобного рода вопроса почитайте литературу / блоги / статьи. В зависимости от необходимых задач вы подберете / придумаете свой правильный в вашем случае способ/патерн.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, есть же тысяча и один вариант.

Например, у вас просто несколько разных `Window`, а при старте программа смотрит на параметры и инстанциирует то или иное окно. Чтобы избежать повторения кода внутри окон, вынесите общие части в `UserControl`'ы.

Или так: меняйте видимость тех или иных контролов в зависимости от условий. `Visibility="Collapsed"` прячет контрол.

Остались нерассмотренными ещё 999 вариантов.

Comment: Эти варианты так же рассматривались) 
Window - да...но...
Свойство Visibility - это получается хаос в разметке) С таким потом будет сложно разобраться.
Все эти варианты рассматривались, но я в поиске чего-нибудь более "элегантного" что ли) Хотелось бы решить эту задачу решить более интересным способом)
Так что там с оставшимися 999 ?)

Comment: А какое «но» в подходе с разными `Window`?

(Самый канонический подход — это паттерн MVVM, но его надо выучить, он большой и непростой.)

Следующий подход: привязать видимость отдельных частей UI к VM (то есть, `DataContext`'у) через `Binding`.

Следующий подход: в корень окна положить `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}/>"`, для различных вариантов `DataContext`'а установить различное отображение через `DataTemplate`.

Comment: это "но" скорее является моим эстетическим "фи") Нет, я не спорю, что это вполне адекватное решение, более того за неимением другого хотел его использовать. Просто я надеялся, что есть какие-нибудь широко известные варианты решения, без нагромождений таких "полноценных" объектов как Window. Потому само окно по идее и не нужно, нужна только его верстка.
Думаю может быть сделать синглтон, который будет предоставлять UserControl-ы, а главный Window использовать как контейнер.
У Window я видел свойство Window.Content, которому можно подсовывать эти UserControl.

Comment: `Window` настолько же «дорогой» объект, как и любой `UserControl`. Но если хотите эстетически адекватное решение, идите от семантики:

1. Внешний контейнер = окно
2. Окно содержит представление контента, то есть, представление _корневой структуры_ контента.
3. Каждая часть контента отображается при помощи соответствующего ему UserControl'а или DataTemplate'а.
4. Бизнес-логика управляет тем, какой контент включается в корневую структуру контента.

Всё, видите, никакая другая логика не нужна.

Comment: Вот Вы подчеркнули "корневой структуры", а если я захочу разбить на несколько "полей отображения" (например: я хочу, чтобы меню висело постоянно одно и то же)... Допустим Frame для этого подойдет?

Comment: Прошу прощения! Вы же в последнем своем сообщении упомянули про ContentPresenter. Он ведь тоже подходит. Сказываются сутки без сна. Думаю, что мой вопрос получил достаточно ответов.
@VladD, огромнейшее спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста! При имплементации наверняка возникнут ещё вопросы, обращайтесь на форум.